# Wrong format obtained for date format for Arabic locale in Mule3

Tags: mule, locale, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am working on a problem where I need to get the date from db and convert the month name to a particular language. It seems to work fine for all languages except for Arabic.

I have used :

```
%var newDate = '2045-12-20' as :date{format : "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

```
%var actualDate = newDate as :string{format : "yyyy/MMM/dd", locale :"ar"}
```

However the output I am getting is in the format yyyy/dd/MM. I have even tried reformatting the output by converting it back to date but it's giving an error of cannot coerce string to date.

Answer (score 0):

DataWeave date handling is based on Java 8 java.time package. The documentation of the class [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) -used for formatting dates- specifies that when using a locale:

> The withLocale method returns a new formatter that overrides the
> locale. The locale affects some aspects of formatting and parsing. For
> example, the ofLocalizedDate provides a formatter that uses the locale
> specific date format.

So it would seem that when using a locale is to be expected that the formatting pattern is overriden. You might want to use a Groovy script, a MEL script or a Java method to implement the format as you desire.